# Behavior (safety) of Java String when converting from invalid (for the charset) byte[]?

Tags: java, string

Is it 100% safe (exception / error free) to convert a byte[] that includes random binary data to a String via the constructor:

```
new String(bytes);
// -- or --
new String(bytes,"UTF-8");  // Or other charset
```

My concern is whether invalid UTF-8 bytes will cause an exception or other failure instead of just a possibly partially garbled message.

I have tried some known bad byte values, as they appear to work as expected.  E.g:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] {'a','b','c',(byte)0xfe,(byte)0xfe,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,'d','e','f'};

String test = new String(bytes,"UTF-8");

System.out.println(test);
```

Prints "abc????def".

My concern is if certain other combinations can fail in other unexpected ways since I cannot guarantee that I can test every invalid combination.

Comment: There is really no *easy* way to ensure that the "garbage" wasn't just the original input for valid byte sequences .. If the source is suspect, frame it with a checksum or other validation method. Although it does bring up the question: how *strict* is string decoding in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

> This method always replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character sequences with this charset's default replacement string

One thing that will fail, if you're not always using UTF-8, is that it can throw [UnsupportedEncodingException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/UnsupportedEncodingException.html).

Comment: Is there a method which would throw an Exception on malformed-input/unmappable-characters?

Comment: Quoting the docs you linked: "The behavior of this constructor when the given bytes are not valid in the given charset is unspecified.".

Comment: @pst no they are replaced with the default replacement, usually `?`. No method would throw an exception since no malformed input is left. If you meant constructors, then yes, [the one which takes `int[] codePoints`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(int[],%20int,%20int)) will throw `IllegalArgumentException` given illegal code points.

Comment: @veer: Oh really? That phrase appears in the javadoc of String(byte[]) and String(byte[], String), which are the constructors the OP used.

Comment: Interesting, the documented behavior for invalid characters changes between `new String(bytes)` and `new String(bytes,charset)`.

Comment: @meriton woops, my fault. He should try `new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

Comment: @parsifal please update your response to explicitly state using a `Charset`.

Comment: Already accepted and upvoted, but veer is correct, for anyone else reading this it may be useful to point out that your comment refers to `String(bytes,charset)` and not `String(bytes)`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to twiddle with decoding behavior on bad inputs, use something like

```
StandardCharsets.UTF_8
  .newDecoder()
  .implOnMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)
  .implOnUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
  .implReplaceWith(replacementString)
  .decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray))
  .toString();
```

which lets you twiddle all the various knobs involved.